# Mesh Self Collision in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, collision

I was wondering if anyone has already succeeded in building a self collision for simulations (or Repeat Zones) in Geometry Nodes.
I have seen several videos for particle collisions on Youtube but none for Meshes.
I understand this is a complex issue and depending on the use case different aspects would be important.
Personally I would like to displace the normals of a mesh depending on a Texture, and let the displacement stop before an intersection happens.
As I understand, the best way to approximate Intersections is to calculate if the next displacement step would bring points below a certain threshold.
So I need to compare the mesh positions before and after the next displacement and see if something goes below the threshold, and undo the displacement at these points? i.e. Mixing the unaltered and altered mesh position depending on the Threshold factor?
I imagine that there would be a benefit in getting the dot product of the near Faces to see if they would grow in the same direction or face each other, especially since I want mainly the nearest parts that are not also the directly connected neighbors (which often point in a similar direction) but other parts coming near, but my attempts at setting this up failed.
Do you have any useful ressources on this or attempted it yourself?
Would be glad to hear about your approaches!
Best, Todesdigga

Comment: I would recommend a [Raycast](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/sample/raycast.html) node as it is providing a *Hit Distance*. So if during the actual iteration/time step, a point should move "inside" the other object, you can clip this distance to maintain it on "the right side". If you need more guidance, could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?